# Is there difference between variable defined outside loop and inside loop?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between declaring variables before or in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop)

```
String str;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    str = "Hello, World"; // Is str created only 1 time?
}
```

What is difference between above and below?
And if they are different, which one is better?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String str = "Hello, World"; // Is str created 10 times?
}
```

Comment: both creates 10 strings.

Comment: @Subin only if you don't account for string interning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't write up your example with a string literal, which is basically a singleton constant, then the answer would be that in both cases 10 objects are created. In your specific example, **no objects are created**.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, the variable can be used out of the scope of *for-loop*, whilst the other one is just visible inside the *for-loop*.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is you can access the `str` variable *after* the loop in the first example.

#### Scope:

The *scope* of the variable is different:

- The variable defined *outside* the loop is accessible *anywhere* the method after it is declared (and initialized), including inside the loop
- The variable defined *inside* the loop is only accessible *inside* the loop

#### Initialization:

If your loop was possible to not iterate, the variable would be uninitialized in the first example, so you couldn't use it after the loop until you gave it a value (even if that value is `null`)

#### Garbage collection:

The point at which it is available for garbage collection is:

1. After the last usage within the method for example 1,
2. At the end of the loop for example 2

Comment: Is that the only difference?

Comment: whether it will be GC-able anywhere before the method end is **not specified** and in practice, the value last assigned may well hang on till the method completes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik good point - edited

Comment: No, actually in the second case, even when it leaves its scope, there is **still** no guarantee that it will be GC-able before the method completes. There was a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531004/java-outofmemoryerror-strange-behaviour) that pointed this out rather dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a string literal its not going to be created 10 times. It's going to be saved in permgen space and not heap space.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, string constants are *interned*, meaning that the same string literal is only kept in (PermGen) memory once, such that eg.:

```
"foo" == "foo"
```

is idempotently true. Thus, both your snippets will be equal in memory footprint, but with the first, you can use `str` after the loop terminates.

Whether one or the other is better, that really depends on what you need to do with `str` after the loop.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

From a maintenance perspective, second is better. Declare and initialize variables in the same place, in the narrowest scope possible. Don't leave a gaping hole between the declaration and the initialization, and don't pollute namespaces you don't need to.

[Refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case a variable global to the loop is initialized with a value whos is reference is changed 10 times whereas in the second case a variable local to the loop is re-initialized 10 times with the same value

Note:There is only one variable and not 10 in both case

Better use an array, vector or linked list for the purpose of multiple variable initialization