# Creating new objects in Thread.run(), when are they garbage collected?

Tags: java

Within a class that extends `Thread`, consider the following example:

```
public void run() {
   while (workToDo) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getNextMap());
        publishJSON(json.toString());
        //  thread sleep
   }
}
```

Is each instance of `json` still referenced as long as the thread is running, or are they freed each time `new` is called?  Should this be moved to a method, i.e. `publishJSON(getJson(getNextMap())`?

Comment: After every loop iteration, it will be available for GC as it goes out of scope.

Comment: They are freed when the GC thinks they should be. Note that when reaching the last sentence of the `while` loop, the object reference hold by `json` variable will be marked for garbage collection.

Comment: @assylias Can you expand?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis there are weird border cases where an out-of-scope, unreachable variable can't be collected. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531004/java-outofmemoryerror-strange-behaviour - note that I don't think that other post applies to the OP's case.

Comment: @assylias Right. _invisible_ state. In that case, always safer to `null` the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a reference to object then it must be a local used variable (while in local scope) or contained in a member variable of a class instance.

I don't see any of the two in your example since after each `while` iteration the local variable can't be referenced anymore. So, unless you do something with `json` that saves a reference to it elsewhere, they are eligible for garbage collection.

Mind that **this doesn't imply that the GC will collect the no-more-referenced instances after every iteration** since its behavior is not predictable from a developer point of view. You just know that eventually they'll be collected.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if scope changed each pass through the loop.

Comment: You don't know that. GC may never run at all. You know that the object is eligible for connection under the conditions stated.